# For the wages of sin is death

Tags: singular-vs-plural

The Bible has a line that I like:

> [Romans 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romans_6#:%7E:text=For%20the%20wages%20of%20sin) (Wikipedia)
>
> For the wages of sin is death

If I wanted to quote that line but be grammatically correct, should I say *wage* (singular), not *wages* (plural)?

> For the wage of sin is death

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'The **wage** of sin is death' would be a [hypercorrection](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hypercorrection), I think. Romans 6:23 is such a well known quotation that you risk being misunderstood, or considered either non-fluent, or excessively pedantic. The word "wages" was historically used as a singular. The word "is" is necessary for the English construction but it is not required for the Greek construction. When it was first translated into English, "wages is" was considered the correct English form.

The Oxford English Dictionary has references from the 14th century to the 18th of 'wages' being considered as singular. The OED’s first citation of this usage is from the 1395 revision of the Wycliffe Bible of 1382: *The wagis of synne is deth.*

Every popular Christian Bible translation, from King James to the English Standard Version, uses this form.

Comment: Particularly in this context: 'death' is singular, and it would be strange to say "The wages of sin *are* death."

Comment: @WeatherVane Why? Would you think it equally strange to say "My wages are a big support"?

Comment: @WS2 no, because death only happens once, and the 'big support' is continual.

Comment: @WeatherVane - but isn't the 'death' in Romans 6:23 a spiritual death that consists, allegedly, of eternal damnation? I am not a theologian, but I gather that 'death' here is translated from the Greek  _θάνατος, (thanatos)_ which does not necessarily mean 'non-existence'.

Comment: But isn't 'eternal damnation' a one-off?

Comment: @WeatherVane - a good point.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, how about "My wages were the death of me", then? A plural verb and a singular complement - nothing odd about that.  In any case I don't really see why a singular word which implies continuity would take a plural verb if it was the subject e.g. "Everlasting life is my ambition".

Comment: @WeatherVane Correcting my earlier mistake in my first comment: The principles of democracy **are** easy to understand. That is the same structure are "the wages of sin".

Answer (score 0):

Typically, we do use the plural:  What wages are now being paid to workers?

The wages of sin suggests it is plural because it is powerful. That is my interpretation of this Biblical poetry.

The plural is used in the King James version of the Bible which is one of its standard translations.